# Periods in CSS Selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

What are the implications of using the various selector configurations?

1. `span.classy.whatever { }`
2. `span.classy, .whatever { }`
3. `span .classy .whatever { }`
4. `span, .classy, .whatever { }`

Comment: This question is much more thorough than the linked duplicate, with correspondingly more thorough answers.

Answer (score 6):

Period in CSS is used to denote the *class* selector. e;g;

Now as per your question Let see where these classes will take effect.

a. `span.classy.whatever { }` : It will affect on span element which has classy and whatever both the classes.

```
<span id="mySpan" class="classy whatever"> Span Text </span>
```

b. `span.classy, .whatever { }`: It will affect on span which has `classy` class and the elements those have `whatever` class.

```
<span id="mySpan" class="classy"> Span Text </span>

<div class="whatever"></div>
```

c. `span .classy .whatever { }`: It will affect on the element which has *whatever* class and the parent of this element would be `classy` and the parent of `classy` would be span.

```
<span>
    <span class="classy">
    <span class="whatever">
        inner most child
    </span>
</span>
```

d. `span, .classy, .whatever { }`: It will affect on the span, elements of *classy* class and *whatever* class.

```
<span>Span Text</span>

<div class="classy"></div>

<p class="whatever"></p>
```

Comment: c is wrong ..... *the element which is decedent of span > element which has classy class and has whatever class.*   Is element with class `whatever` who is inside another with class `classy` and inside a `span`

Comment: @Danko Yes element which has `whatever` class and have the `classy` as parent and the parent of classy is `span`. I re-phrase my line. May be it was confusing earlier.

Answer (score 1):

1) will apply to all the spans with .classy and .whatever classes.

2) will apply to all the spans with .classy and all the elements with .whatever classes

3) will apply to all the elements with .whatever class which should be a child of an element with class .classy which inturn should be a child of a span. eg

```
<span>
   <div class="classy">
      <div class="whatever">This will be targeted</div>
   </div>
</span>
```

4) will apply to all spans, .classy and .whatever classes

Answer (score 1):

They all mean different things and select different elements.

```
span.classy.whatever { }
```

The rules are applied to a `<span>` element that belongs to a class `classy` and a class `whatever`.

```
span.classy, .whatever { }
```

The rules are applied to a `<span>` element that belongs to a class `classy`, and to ANY element that belongs tho the class `whatever`.

```
span .classy .whatever { }
```

The rules are applied to an element that belongs to the `whatever` class that in a descendant of an element that belongs to the `classy` class that is a descendant of a `<span>` element.

```
span, .classy, .whatever { }
```

The rules are applied to ANY `<span>` element, ANY element that belongs to the `classy` class and ANY element that belongs to the `whatever` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
span.classy.whatever { }
```

This will match a `span` element, that has a class of `classy` and `whatever`

```
span.classy, .whatever { }
```

Will match a `span` element that has a class of `classy` and `any` element with the `whatever` class

```
span .classy .whatever { }
```

Will match a nested element

```
<span>
    <span class="classy">
        <span class="whatever">here</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

And finally

```
span, .classy, .whatever { }
```

Will match all `span` elements, and `any` element with with a class of `classy` and any element with a class of `whatever`

Answer (score 0):

`span.classy.whatever { }`

Targets `span` elements with both `.classy` and `.whatever` classes

`span.classy, .whatever { }`

Targets `span` elements with the class `.classy` and any element with the class `.whatever`

`span .classy .whatever { }`

Targets elements that have the class `.whatever` that are the children of elements with the class `.classy` that are children of `span` elements.

`span, .classy, .whatever { }`

Targets any `span` element, and any elements with either the class `.classy` or `.whatever`